# org.testng.testngexception cannot instantiate class cucmber-testng error

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to use testNG framework in cucumber. But getting below error.

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 8.032 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-02T16:11:29+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/220M    
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project TestCaseAPI: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class com.XXX.automation.feature.RunCuke1Test
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
```

My runner class is as follow:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions (features = "src/test/resources/feature"
    ,glue="com.XXX.automation.feature"
    ,monochrome=true
    )
    public class RunCuke1Test extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {       
    }
```

My testNG.xml is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="Test diary">
<classes>
<class name="com.XXX.automation.feature.RunCuke1Test"/> 
</classes> 
</test>
</suite>
```

My project structure is as above:
[image]

I am running it through Maven

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are mixing testng and junit test: start by removing `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`

Comment: Check sample from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng

Comment: You cannot use TestNG for Cucumber. Use Junit to execute the Cucumber class.

Answer (score 1):

I did recheck on cucumber-testNG maven dependency. Earlier I was using older version. I am now using the latest version and now my program is running successfully now.